# Android progress indicator increments at once in a for loop

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar

I want to increment a progress indicator while scanning all the files in my device. here is a simplified implementation:

```
val totalFiles = 10000
progressBar.max = totalFiles
repeat(totalFiles) {
    Thread.sleep(5) // to slow the loop for debugging purposes
    binding.circularProgress.incrementProgressBy(1)
}
```

The progress bar is supposed to increment by 1 every 5 ms, but instead, it increments at once after the loop has finished. I don't understand why this isn't working. Any idea guys? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` blocks the main UI thread and the progressbar does not get a chance to update itself.

Rather than blocking the main thread, use some concurrency mechanism (rxjava, coroutines, asynctask, raw threads) to do your processing, posting UI updates to the main thread.